# Output of ffmpeg into HDFS directly

Tags: hadoop, video, ffmpeg, hdfs, rtsp

I have a requirement in which I have to convert a RTSP stream into mp4 video or frames (as the case may be) & want to save them in HDFS (Hadoop Filesystem).

For this I have tried using ffmpeg to convert the RTSP stream into mp4 video/frames & saving the video/frames in local filesystem. Like below -
`ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/big_bunny.mkv -r 1 -f image2 frames/big_frame-%3d.bmp`
`ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/big_bunny.mkv big_bunny.mp4`

And then saving the video/frames (stored in local filesystem) into hdfs using put command -
`hadoop fs -put frames/ /user/maddy/`
`hadoop fs -put big_bunny.mp4 /user/maddy/`

This is working. But I want to do this directly (that is in one step without saving the required files in local filesystem)

I tried something (like below command) but it is not working
`ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/big_bunny.mkv hdfs://localhost:9000/user/maddy/big_bunny.mp4`

I get this error -
`hdfs://localhost:9000/user/maddy/big_bunny.mp4: Protocol not found`

So is there any way in which using ffmpeg I can directly save these files into hdfs without first saving in my local filesystem.
Or is there any other tool through which I can achieve this?

EDIT :

Tried `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/big_bunny.mkv - | hadoop fs -put - /user/maddy/`
as suggested by @incBrain

But received this error -
`[NULL @ 0xce37a0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
pipe:: Invalid argument`

Comment: can you try this: `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/big_bunny.mkv - | hadoop fs -put - /user/maddy/`?

Comment: @incBrain Tried this but it is also not working..edited the question with the error that I got after running the above command.

Comment: Hmm then `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/big_bunny.mkv pipe:1 | hadoop fs -put - /user/maddy/` should do it. I hope. If not, maybe the redirection to a named pipe using `>` can be a solution.

Comment: @incBrain No it is also not working. Also I didn't try redirection to a named pipe as I am not aware about it.

Comment: @incBrain This is working `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/test.mkv -f avi pipe: | hadoop fs -put - /user/maddy/test.avi` . The `-f` argument was missing which specifies the video format in which to decode. Although when I give `-f mp4` it doesn't work. Btw Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @incBrain Another edit your first suggested command is also working by including `-f` argument. `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/test.mkv -f avi - | hadoop fs -put - /user/maddy/test.avi` . You can add an answer giving these commands. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the output of `ffmpeg` to a pipe and use `hadoop fs -put - /user/...` to [read the input from `stdin`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.37.150:8554/test.mkv -f avi - | hadoop fs -put - /user/maddy/test.avi
```

Note that you will need [`-f <format>` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) since `ffmpeg` can not guess the output format from the file extension since we use our pipe.

Comment: Can we do it without installing Hadoop in our local system and need to push to remote HDFS?