# How to slice data into HDFS by using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hdfs, slice, segment

I checked here "[Output of ffmpeg into HDFS directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38097146/output-of-ffmpeg-into-hdfs-directly?answertab=active#tab-top)" we can put ffmpeg data into HDFS .

How to slice data into HDFS by using FFMpeg Segment muxer?